# How can i read certain parts of of a text file and store them in character arrays to be compared?

Tags: c

here is the part of the program that i am struggling with, "You will need some kind of loop to read through the entries in a text file, for the 1st 4 fields in the text file, you will know that you are at the end of the field when you read a comma. For the last field in the text file, you will know you are at the end of the field when you read a newline.

I did the program using functions from string.h but was challenged do the same program without the use of string.h and i am stuck at the loop part of this program.

i know my loop is incorrect but i am having trouble figuring out the correct loop to use, any tips will be helpfully

```
do
{
    ch = fgetc(fout);
    if(ch == EOF)
    {
        break;
    }


    field[x]=ch;//loads all the characters into the array

    printf("%c",field[x]);//printing 
    x++;

}while(1);//infinite loop

fclose(fout);
```

Comment: Since you are looping and wanting to find the first 4-comma-separated fields in each *line*, why not use a *line-oriented* input function like `fgets()` to read a line-at-a-time into a buffer and then iterate over each character in the buffer looking for your comma or newline. You can do it either way. In the case of `fgetc()` you will need to buffer the characters between delimiters anyway, you may as well read them into a buffer to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be to make a 2dimensional array so a array of field and have an if in the loop that increments the variable that says which field array to use when there is a comma. You would end up with 5 char arrays that each have one field, and you'd have a \n in the last one Wich you then need to remove.
Hope this helps